# How to make a drop shadow on a custom shape

Tags: android, android-studio, dropshadow

I want something like this:
[image: I want something like this:]

I have the shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        <corners android:radius="15dip" />
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/shadow" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

But my problem is the shadow, is there a way I can do this?

Comment: This can easily be done by just adding `android:elevation` on your button if you want to set your minSdkVersion to 21.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24179336/android-layout-with-rounded-drop-shadow

Comment: I beleive such button was made using nine-patch for pre-lollipop devices

Comment: Elevation does not work because I already have a background set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CardView to create shadow view in android

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
```

1. `card_view:cardElevation="3dp"` this is for shadow
2. `card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"` this is for corner radius

Comment: From what I know CardView is used from API 24 and there are not so many users using android 7, are there other ways to do this?

Comment: you can use v7 support library for below compatibility.